# Show facebook like button on a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I want a facebook like button through Iframe. For that I got facebook like code from [facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) . The code was like this

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fplugins%2Flike&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Now I want that instead of url link `http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fplugins%2Flike` (I don't know is this the proper Url) I want my url to pass in that code. So for that I have made my code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str=document.URL;
document.write('<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+str+'&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
</script>
```

But its not working. So can someone kindly tell me what is the wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

take your Facebook page link and give it in the Facebook follow this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
put your link in the form 
and then they will give you the whole iframe